# How to execute SQL queries from text files

Tags: sql, database, sybase, aquafold

I am using Aqua Data Studio 7.0.39 for my Database Stuff. 
I have a 20 SQL files(all contains sql statements, obviously).

I want to execute all rather than copy-paste contains for each.

Is there any way in Aqua to do such things.

Note: I am using Sybase

Thank you !!

Comment: I'd suggest to visit Aqua Studio site: https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also not sure of how to do this in Aqua, but it's very simple to create a batch/powershell script to execute .sql files

You can use the SAP/Sybase `isql` utility to execute files, and just create a loop to cover all the files you wish to execute.

Check my answer here for more information:
[Running bulk of SQL Scripts in Sybase through batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300180/running-bulk-of-sql-scripts-in-sybase-through-batch/16303043#16303043)

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of ADS there is an integrated shell named FluidShell where  you can achieve what you are looking for. See an overview here: https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation15/page/246/FluidShell

The command you are looking for is [source](https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation15/page/289/source)

source
NAME
source - execute commands or SQL statements from a file

SYNOPSIS
source [OPTION...] FILE [ARGUMENT...]
source [OPTION...]

DESCRIPTION
Read and execute commands or SQL statements from FILE in the current shell environment.

Comment: yeah. but unfortunately I am using the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Aquafold before so I can't tell you exactly. However I have tackled a similar problem once before.

I once created a Powershell script. It opened a ODBC connection to my database and then executed stored procedures in a loop until end of file.

I suggest having a text document with each line being the name of an Stored Proc to run. Then in your powershell script read in a line from the file concatenate it into the call to execute a stored procedure. After each execution is completed you can delete the line from the text file and then read the next line until the EOF (end of file) is reached.

Hope this helps. If I have some time this morning I will try and do a working example for you and post it.

Comment: My apologies I just noticed you are using Sybase... Meaning the powerhsell script is probably a little bit pointless.. I do however know some Sybase developers at work. I will ask their opinions and come back to you.

Comment: That will be great. Thanks